# No Wayland with my new Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: boot, 22.04, thinkpad, wayland, amdgpu

> Edited: Made a mistake my version is 23.04 not 22.04. That changes
> everything. Will close this question as soon as new installation
> solves the problem.

I can't make Wayland to work on my Thinkpad A485 Laptop with Ryzen 3 AMD (previously on 20.04 it worked).
I installed from the LiveUSB created with MkUSB (to have a persistent drive). But the behaviour is:

- When i boot everything is text only till the login screen.
- No option to change between Xorg and Wayland

Changed **/etc/gdm3/custom.conf**   uncommenting (#) and editing so it reads:

```
WaylandEnable = true
```

Changed the file **/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules** commenting every single line ( # )

No luck so far. The syslog messages associated with wayland used to say:

```
syslog.1:2023-05-25T21:34:39.527556-06:00 thinkpad systemd[2447]: Starting org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service - GNOME Shell on Wayland...
syslog.1:2023-05-25T21:34:39.533462-06:00 thinkpad systemd[2447]: org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service: Skipped due to 'exec-condition'.
syslog.1:2023-05-25T21:34:39.533627-06:00 thinkpad systemd[2447]: Condition check resulted in org.gnome.Shell@wayland.service - GNOME Shell on Wayland being skipped.
```

Changed grub to include:

```
amdgpu.cik_support=1 amdgpu.si_support=1 radeon.si_support=0 radeon.cik_support=0
```

Comment: The login screen only show the choice (gear icon lower right) when the password field is displayed.  If Wayland is the default, it will only say Ubuntu/xorg for a choice.  Does ps auxw |grep -i wayl show any wayland processes?

Comment: Thank you for you comment ubfan1, that command shows nothing (only itself)

Comment: Have poked around trying to start Wayland directly from console (as a troubleshooting step)? Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/38546347/768176

Comment: Tried but failed it says:
Failed to setup: No GPUs found

Answer (score 0):

hope it work with you

DefaultSession=gnome-wayland.desktop

source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387484/debian-stretch-how-do-i-make-wayland-the-default

Comment: Thankyou zdo, it didn't work, besides is a 5 year old answer and seems the problem is the new ubuntu 23.04

Answer (score 0):

Downgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 (actually reinstall everything). I found no way to user Ubuntu 23.04 with my laptop.

Thank you zdo, ckhan and ubfan1, for your comments.

The problem persists and is probably related with the new Kernel, since no GPU were found, beign that AMD should be handled with no extra drivers.